# Converting a factor which contains character values to integer

Tags: r

I have a factor-variable which contains integer and character values. I would like to extract only integer values.
I try my code:

```
m <- c(k[,1])
m <- as.vector.factor(k[,1])
h <- c()
for (k in m) {
  if(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(k)))) {
    h<-c(h,k)
  }
}
h <- as.numeric(h)
h
```

It works fine, but I think there is another better way. Do you have any recommendation? How can I do it better?

```
m<-as.vector.factor(k[,1])
m
 [1] "Text"                           "Test: Text, Text"  "Text"                                        
 [4] "Text"                                         ""                                                    ""                                                   
 [7] "1990"                                                "1991"                                                "1992"                                               
[10] "1993"                                                "1994"                                                "1995"                                               
[13] "1996"                                                "1997"                                                "1998"                                               
[16] "1999"                                                "2000"                                                "2001"                                               
[19] "2002"                                                "2003"                                                "2004"                                               
[22] "2005"                                                "2006"                                                "2007"                                               
[25] "2008"                                                "2009"                                                "2010"                                               
[28] "2011"                                                "2012"                                                "2013"                                               
[31] "2014"                                                "2015"                                                "__________"                                         
[34] "Text" "Text"
```

Comment: I think you want https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: but in this way it gives me also NA back. I dont need NAs

Comment: Take a look at `na.omit` to filter those out.

Comment: Maybe: `x <- as.factor(c("Text", "1991","Test: Text, Text", "1992","__________","Text")); na.omit(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x)))`